# Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict with a package already installed

Tags: deployment, uwp, msdeploy, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have converted an .EXE application using DesktopAppConverter, I have the .appX file. I installed the auto-generated certificate. Now When I try to install the appX file in my computer I get this error

> Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict with a package already installed, or it depends on things not installed here (package dependencies), or is made for a different architecture (0x80073CF3)

How Can I fix this??

the converter at one point says

> VERBOSE: Added a new framework package dependency based on file 'C:\vfs0\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Fun
>    Money\msvcp120.dll'. Package name: 'Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop'
>   WARNING: DesktopAppConverter : warning 'W_PACKAGE_DEPENDENCY_ADDED': A dependency on framework package
>   'Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop' was added to the AppxManifest.xml. See
>   'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821959' for guidance on installing the package prior to local deployment.
>   Otherwise, if this is in error, remove the corresponding entry from Dependencies in the AppxManifest.xml before
>   packaging and deploying your application.
>   VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------

I did visit *go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821959* and I installed VC 14, 12 and 11. But Still The same error.

**Note** The appManifest.xml in .appX file (used winrar to open it) have this dependencies

```
 <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="12.0.40652.5" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
```

Yet when I visit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14.0`

I only have the 14.0 version to install no 12.0 folder exists.

I'm not sure if this note helps fixing the problem but I added just in case.

Comment: Just to double-check, did you actually deploy the Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.12.00.Universal.appx package (and/or the respective x64 one) using add-appxpackage on the target system?

Comment: I installed this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53175 and other versions (12 & 11) by download and installing them by double click. I'm not sure what do you mean by add-appxpackage?

Comment: I will write it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

When sideloading an .appx package that has dependencies, those dependencies are not downloaded from the Windows Store automatically. You will need to explicitly install them on the target machine. Users who get your app from the Store won't need to do this, the Store will install for them.

Here is how you do it in the sideloading scenario:
- open a powershell command prompt
- locate the .appx package for your dependency (in this case 'Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.12.00.Universal.appx')
- run Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.12.00.Universal.appx 
- now try deploying your app package again

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: "Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.12.00.Universal" is an .EXE file not .appX. where can I download .appX file. if Itry to publish the .appX file in the store will it works for people who get the application from there or will they run into the same error as me?? Can I upload the the folder (containing .appX file and other files) in the internet for you to download and test on your local machine?? that would be great